# How do I include a button in product.liquid file using REST api in shopify?

Tags: shopify

How do I include a button in product.liquid file using REST api in shopify? also need to change button style dynamically using API. without edit liquid file, only using API.

Answer (score 0):

There's no safe way to do this because to use the API you'd have to include your keys in the public JS.